# Controlling Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rvm

Forgive me if there's a duplicate, but I'm honestly not sure what to search for. I'm working on a project with Ruby on Rails, and I get this message when doing anything related (ie: rake, rails, rspec, etc.):

> Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3

Now, I've installed RVM and I can fix this issue by issuing the command

`bash --login`

*edit for clarity*

running the above command does use Ruby 2.2.3 to execute the commands.

*/edit*

Then those given commands work. What I would like to do is to remove version 2.1.5 entirely -- leaving only 2.2.3. I've gone about this so many different ways, but Ruby is pretty foreign territory to me so I'm not sure what to do about this. I'm sure I have at least three installations of Ruby on my machine - possibly two duplicates of the two versions I know I have - and I would like only one version and to avoid needing to enter the `bash --login` command in order to run my project.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 and have at least some knowledge of how this works. If somebody could walk me through removing everything related to Ruby & Ruby on Rails, then installing only Ruby 2.2.3 and Rails 4.2.4, I would greatly appreciate that. Let me know if this isn't the proper exchange for this question. It didn't quite seem to fit into Ubuntu or Sysadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is not try to remove `ruby 2.1.5`.

You have RVM, so, use that to get the new version you want.

After this, you now have two options:

1) [make the newly installed version the global default version](https://rvm.io/rubies/default) on your machine,

or

2) [create a gemset for your project](https://rvm.io/gemsets), and specify the needed ruby version for the project.

Either of these will fix your problem.

Comment: What exactly is a gemset? Alternatively, how do I change the global default? I've tried `update-alternatives` but it says there are no available alternatives for Ruby, and symlink hacks aren't working either.

Here is my gemfile: [link](http://i.snag.gy/C6knh.jpg)

Comment: I just included a link to gemsets on the second option. Kindly check that.

Comment: And I just included a link for making a ruby version the default version too.

Comment: Thank you. As it turns out, this was a common/expected [issue with Ubuntu](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal), but I appreciate the instructions on setting the default and gemsets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the Gemfile.

http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile_ruby.html

Comment: I am locked into using version 2.2.3. Changing the gemfile to use 2.1.5 won't fix any of the problems listed, unless I'm severely misunderstanding what you're suggesting.

Comment: well you're setting the ruby version bundler will use in Gemfile (or via .rvm_version file) if you followed the above link. So to use that version you must prefix your gem commands with "bundle exec" otherwise you'll leverage your system version of ruby. You don't need to uninstall your system ruby.

Comment: I don't want version 2.1.5 at all. I have no use for it. I want to change my system ruby to 2.2.3, not change the project. l:

Comment: then this isn't an RVM question. Just install the appropriate version of ruby from source. download, extract, ./configure, make, sudo make install